# perl split problem with repeated delimiter (comma)

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have problem with repeated delimiter (comma)

String input

```
abc : {A=[2, 2, 2], B=x, C=[1, 1, 1, 1], D=1}
```

my code

```
if ($_ =~ /^(\w+)\s+:\s+\{(\S+=.*)\}/)
{
  my $attr_struct = $1; 
  my $sub_attr_struct = $2;
  $sub_attr_struct =~ s/,\s+/,/g;
  my @sub_attr_struct_split = split(',',$sub_attr_struct);
  foreach my $attr (@sub_attr_struct_split)
   {
    print "$attr_struct".".$attr\n";  
   }
 }
```

Expected output is

```
abc.A=2:2:2
abc.B=x
abc.C=1:1:1:1 
abc.D=1
```

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to `split` on commas when commas are parts of the fields to obtain; would need a complex regex for the separator pattern, which would be brittle for a variety of data.<sup>†</sup>

Instead, one way

```
my ($w, $c) = /(\w+) \s+:\s+ { (.+) }/x; 

my @t = $c =~/ ([^=]+ = (?:\[ [^\]]+ \] | \w+) ) (?:,\s+)? /gx; 

s/,\s+/:/g for @t;
```

In a command-line program, for a ready test drive

```
perl -wE'$_=q(abc : {A=[2, 2, 2], B=x, C=[1, 1, 1, 1], D=1}); 
    say; say"-"x40;
    ($w, $c) = /(\w+) \s+: \s+{ (.+) }/x; 
    say $w; 
    @t = $c =~/ ([^=]+ = (?:\[ [^\]]+ \] | \w+) ) (?:,\s+)? /gx;
    s/,\s+/:/g for @t;
    say for @t '
```

This *can* be squeezed in one regex but I absolutely agree with the question in breaking it up first.

It prints

```
abc : {A=[2, 2, 2], B=x, C=[1, 1, 1, 1], D=1}
----------------------------------------
abc
A=[2:2:2]
B=x
C=[1:1:1:1]
D=1
```

Can form the exact desired output as

```
my @terms = map { "$w.$_" } @t;
```

---

Comments

- First split input into the word (before `:`) and content of the following curlies.
- Then in curlies match: all up to `=`, then `=`, then either `[...]` or word char(s) (`x` or `1`, etc).
- The match runs globally (`/g`) for the whole string, returning all such patterns.  But the intervening `,`  is optional (`(?,\s+)?`) since the last term isn't followed by it.
- What else can follow `=` in the actual data?
- The use of the negated character class (`[^=]+`, `[^\]]+`) provides for non-greedy matching as these patterns match sequences up to the first occurrence of that character.
- Expression `s/,\s+/:/g for @t` uses the fact that in a `for` loop the topical variable, `$_` here, is an alias for the elements iterated over; changing it changes elements (unless they are string literals, which are read-only).  So `s///` changes elements of `@t`.

  This is in general not good practice but in this form I consider it a bit of an idiom since it is very distinct and once you know what it does it is crystal clear and obvious.  Please re-write more nicely if it isn't.

---

<sup>†</sup> For example

```
my @t = split / (?<= \]|=\w) ,\s* /x, $inside_curlies;
```

This [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split)s on a comma that is preceded by either `]` or a `=\w`. It produces the correct result on the given string, but we can't say `=\w+` since the [lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) `(?<= ...)` can't take patterns with arbitrary-length matches (what `\w+` does).

So we can't match like this if it could be `B=x` *or* `B=x1`.   In newer Perls the lookbehind works for matches of variable length up to 255 characters.  So we *could* say `(?<= \]|=\w{1,254))`, if we know that what follows `=` isn't longer.  But this becomes awkward.

Other modifications of data are easy to imagine which also couldn't be easily accommodated for.

This is relegated to a footnote since I don't think that it is a good solution.